# How to customize GNOME Shell Search bar?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I would like to include stackoverflow, duckduckgo and some other search results in GNOME Shell Search result. So, I think a GNOME Shell Extension will be the solution. Is it possible?

Comment: I too wanted to write a search provider for gnome shell. I tried to look for ANY similar extension, so that I could fork it, but as of today there's no extension in the market that is not broken in Gnome 3.36.2 (the one I have).